# RAP: How to access Object in ViewPart

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

how do I access to an `Object` of a `View` from somewhere else?

(Following code is just to sketch what i want to do)

```
public class View extends ViewPart {

    public static final String ID = "view";
    private static List list;

    public View() {
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        list = new List(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }

    public static void addToList(String string) {
        list.add(string);
    }
}
```

Now I want be able to use `View.addToList("Message")` anywhere in the application.

Comment: Wait, why can't you just make a getter function?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Because he knows that he wouldn't instantiate a `View` :)

Comment: @RomanC Ohohohohohohohohohohohho. You mean this would be a static class? With member variables !?!?!?!

Comment: @thatidiotguy Anyway he must know when widget is created.

Comment: @JohnSmith I would just reconsider my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code snippet, and replace `[ID]` with the id you specified for your view in `plugin.xml`.

```
IViewPart viewPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView( [ID] );
```

The id is usually in the form of `com.domain.something.viewName` and can be found under your view contribution.

Comment: [ID] should be "view" in my example? And where do i use this snippet; how does this "findView" helps me?

Comment: If it's the same as in your plugin.xml view contribution, then sure :)

Comment: Oh ok i got it. Thx a lot for helping ;)

Comment: @Knownasilya It will not work if calling from the other window or perspective.

Comment: @RomanC Since only one perspective is displayed at one time, not sure if that would make it a big problem, unless you do something in the background in which case you still run in the current perspective, right? If I'm wrong, is there another way that would work always?

Comment: @Knownasilya See my answer below.

Comment: @Knownasilya With this solution you are in face of `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

The `View` as well as `ViewPart` is registered in the `ViewRegistry` when workbench is started. The `Workbench` contains all registered views and editors. The simplest way to get information for that view from the workbench registry. First you check if `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().isStarting()`. Once this method returns `false` you can get

```
IViewDescriptor descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().find("view");
```

When workbench is started it registers all views and editors contributed to it but to run your code you need make sure the workbench is running and you have an instance of the view.

To create an instance of the `View` you would use the code

```
try {
    IViewPart view = descriptor.createView();
    view.createPartControl();
} catch (CoreException e) {
    // TODO something with e
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now you `be able to use View.addToList("Message") anywhere in the application`.

Comment: So how do you get the view from the registry?

Comment: @Knownasilya I have described the process in detail.