# Changing function prototype generates "cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced" error

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In researching this problem, I've run into a lot of posts that have seen errors similar to the title of this post. This problem is different in that the error only shows up when I try to pass *String* to functions of a plugin class I'm developing.

I did find one post [RAP: How to access Object in ViewPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221594/rap-how-to-access-object-in-viewpart) that may be hinting at my issue.

Although I'm running Eclipse 3.6.1, I think this question is about general Java. My main issue is that I have a class (class A) in one Eclipse project that uses another class (class B) in an Eclipse plug-in project. A cannot call any functions of class B that require a *String* as one of the arguments. I generated a dummy class C (along with a dummy Java project) that uses class B and I still have the same issues. Let me elaborate some.

I have two projects in Eclipse. One of them is an Eclipse plugin project that contains a class that is essentially a plotter and that extends *org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart*. I am instantiating this plotter class from another non-plugin project which cannot call any member functions from the plotter class that expect a *String* as one of the arguments.

For example, the following code snippet:

```
Plotter myPlotter = new Plotter();    
myPlotter.plot();
```

works correctly when run from my non-plugin project. If, however, I modify *plot* to expect a *String* (say, for a label), or even create a new function that prints a *String*:

```
Plotter myPlotter = new Plotter();
String theString = "I'm the String";
myPlotter.plot(theString);
myPlotter.printMe(theString);
```

Eclipse gives me red underlines under *printMe* and *plot* indicating an error. When I hover over *printMe*, I get the error:
*The type org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files*

To try to understand this problem a little better, I built another two classes in the plugin project to test the issue, one whose superclass is *java.lang.Object*, the other whose superclass is *org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart*. I can call functions with *String* arguments from the *Object*-based class but I cannot call functions with String as arguments from the *ViewPart*-based class. So it has something to do with *ViewPart* (I can drill down to subsequent superclasses and still have the problem if the class inherits from *EventManager*). Just for kicks, I tried changing the class so it extends *Vector* and my problem disappears. It looks to me like the problem is related to *EventManager* and/or *ViewPart*.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perform a clean on all projects (Project -> Clean).  That might help.

Comment: @ChrisGerken -- I thought that was a good idea which I hadn't tried. Unfortunately, it didn't improve my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a runtime issue, so how you run your program does not matter. You get *compilation* errors.

Chris Gerken is right, but you didn't try his solution, so I will try to explain why he is right.

When the Java compiler looks at your code, it needs to know the definition of the classes you call. Sometimes it needs to know the definition of all inherited members as well (for instance, when resolving overloaded method calls). You seem to have hit that case. Now, if your classpath contains only your *plotter* project, and not the jars that define the `ViewPart`, it will fail with this message.

You can solve it by adding the correct jar on your classpath (you'd need to fiddle a bit to find out in which jar it's defined). Otherwise, you can export all libraries on the plotter classpath (Project Properties/Java Build Path, Order and Export tab - select all).

Chris' solution goes around this by creating a new interface (that does not extend anything), hosted by the plotter project. Using that interface has no dependencies (but you need to be able to create one, hence the factory).

Comment: I exported everything in my plug-in class and I'm good to go. I am confused as to why there were no compile-time errors when I first compiled and ran the class. It must have been finding the classes implicitly at first. Then, I added a String argument to the method I was calling and all-of-a-sudden a dependency problem is generated. It was accessing the superclasses before so it obviously knew where to find them before I added the String. Any ideas as to what changed that kept it from finding the class implicitly?

Answer (score 0):

OK. As I read the question, you're trying to instantiate an object whose superclass (ViewPart) is not in the class path, even though the part itself is in the classpath.  Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but the referencing project isn't a plugin and so it doesn't have the PDE container in its classpath to provide these other classes.

I can only suggest that you not instantiate the class directly, but rather obtain an instance from a factory-like class in the plotter's plugin.  Do this by:

- creating an interface in the plotter's plugin
- making the plotter implement this interface
- making the factory return an instance of the interface.

This should let you do what you want.

btw... the instance should define whatever methods you want to call on the plotter.

Comment: As I think about this some more... How do you expect to run this non-plugin?  You have to run it in Eclipse to get the eEclipse behavior, but the project itself is not an Eclipse plugin.  I suppose you could write it as a pluglet, but I haven't seen one of those for a long time.

Comment: I must admit I didn't understand everything you said in your "Answer" post. But...did you note in my posting that I have no trouble running the plugin UNTIL I add a String as a function argument? Wouldn't that suggest that it's not a classpath issue? I'm extending the class so I have defined a new method for the class. I would like method to accept a *String* as one of its arguments.

Comment: I don't think your answer applies to my situation since I already have a working plugin. But I think all others are ignoring my post since you "Answered" my problem. Could you "unanswer" it?

Comment: How are you running the tool?

Comment: Within Eclipse. I'm instantiating the plugin class from my non-plugin class. I run this latter class as a Java Application from within eclipse. Does this surprise you?

Comment: In any case, it does what I expect. It's not in a state that I can deliver it, but it's working to the point that I can test my plots to make them look like I want them to. Only when I modify my plot method to accept a string do things fail to compile. Why is is that I cannot create methods in a class that extends ViewPart that accepts a String as an argument?

Comment: Okay -- I think what you're getting at is a setting I have in the plugin MANIFEST.MF. I have the option to activate the plugin when any of the plugin classes are loaded. I have selected that option. I think that resulted in an Activator class being installed in Eclipse. So when I instantiate the class, this is probably why things kick off properly.

Comment: I don't think you're running this in an Eclipse environment which you must do for ViewPart.  Running in an Eclipse Environment is different than running an app from Eclipse as a Java application.  If you want the answer removed you need to flag it as inappropriate or goto http://meta.stackoverflow.com and create a question stating your case for the removal of this answer.  I hope you get this solved.